# Does my Water-Heater stand need to be metal or fire rated drywall?

Tags: water-heater

I have a water heater that is on a plywood stand over 18" high. Does the stand need to be replaced with a metal stand or fire rated drywall?

Comment: No. They sit on unfinished wooden subfloors all the time.

Comment: You're welcome, but please use voting and answer acceptance for showing gratitude. We're not a discussion forum. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are codes written for how to install appliances, especially gas ones. There is also specific rules for how to install drinking water appliances, so in the course of a Water Heater, you have both.

Here is an example (google) for [Las Vegas Nevada](https://www.lasvegasnevada.gov/cs/groups/public/documents/document/dhn0/mday/~edisp/tst002210.pdf). That is just an example. You should check your local county/town ordinance and verify their rules. Also, check your water heater model # and read the manufacturers guidelines.

I'm not too sure why you would use drywall for a stand? Is there a different portion of the question you meant to ask? You would not want to frame a stand out of Drywall. Conversely, Making a stand out of plywood works, but only if it meets code and is well built to hold the load of the water + tank weight + some % buffer (say, 25% SWAG).

Anyways, here is a really good discussion on this very topic here: [How high to raise water heater above floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/83038/how-high-to-raise-water-heater-above-floor)

Oh, I almost forgot - based on code & manufacturer, you may not have to raise it at all, but the cinder block approach is pretty foolproof.